# Яндекс.Контест - Wrong-Answer на третьем тесте

Tags: java, алгоритм

Решаю [задачу по алгоритмам](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kbsxsdy029myyyt/photo_2023-02-17_10-20-30.jpg?dl=0) на Яндекс.Контесте.

**Условие задачи**

Красотой строки назовем максимальное число идущих подряд одинаковых букв. (красота строки abcaabdddettq равна 3)

Сделайте данную вам строку как можно более красивой, если вы можете сделать не более k операций замены символа.

**Формат ввода.**
Первая строка положительный int k. Вторая строка String непустая строка.

**Формат вывода**
Выведите одно число — максимально возможную красоту строчки, которую можно получить.

**Примеры:**

```
Ввод  
2 
abcaz 

Вывод 
4
```

```
Ввод  
2 
helto 

Вывод 
3
```

В IDEA получаю ожидаемый результат, но на сайте не проходит последний [тест](https://www.dropbox.com/s/16fabmqy83l29ay/photo_2023-02-17_10-21-08.jpg?dl=0). В чем причина того, что последний тест не проходит?

Код решения на Java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(Path.of("input.txt"));
        int count = Integer.parseInt(list.get(0));
        String word = list.get(1);
        Map<Character, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
        for (char ch : word.toCharArray()) {
            if (!map.containsKey(ch)) {
                map.put(ch, 0);
            }
            map.put(ch, map.get(ch) + 1);
        }
        int maxCharCount = map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue))
            .get().getValue();
        int result = maxCharCount + count;
        if (result >= word.length()) {
            result = word.length();
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: добавь саму задачу в вопрос, и входные и ожидаемые данные

Comment: Подход неверный, у вас же учитывается только количество символов, а их расположение полностью игнорируется.  `2 abcadeafga` что у вас выдаст? Подозреваю, что 6, а нужно 4

Comment: В примере 2 abcaz результат 4. По этой же логике должно получиться 6. Или у меня логика неправильная?

Comment: Интересная задачка. Дайте знать, пожалуйста, если кто-то знает алгоритм решения

Comment: @Аброр Мирзаев  `По этой же логике должно получиться 6` - по какой логике? Заменив b и с на а, получим длину 4

Comment: Chat GPT выдал 4)

Comment: @MBo спасибо большое. Теперь понял.

Comment: Просто посмотри решение данной задачки: https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, задачу можно решить с использованием метода двух указателей (индексов).

Ставим left и right в 0, и начинаем двигать правый индекс. На каждом шаге модифицируем мап, аналогичный тому, что вы уже сделали, увеличивая счетчик для текущего символа. Как только количество "побочных" символов в окне превысит количество замен, останавливаемся, сравниваем величину окна (разность right-left) с максимально достигнутой.

Теперь двигаем левый индекс, на каждом шаге уменьшая счетчик для уходящего из окна символа. Как только количество "побочных символов" в окне станет равно количеству замен, останавливаемся.

Повторяем процедуру.

Побочные символы - все, кроме символа с максимальным счетчиком

Answer (score 0):

Небольшое дополнение к замечательному ответу @MBo - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1497134/551745

Решаем методом динамического плавающего окна через два итератора.

1. Мы должны считать не просто побочные символы, а считать именно их сумму, так как побочные символы могут быть разбросаны в разном количестве внутри окна
2. Чтобы найти побочные символы внутри окна, необходимо так же найти и символ с максимальными символами внутри текущего окна

Напишу на котлине, но думаю принцип вы поймете и на джаве:

```
fun beautyOfString(s: String, k: Int): Int {
    val frequencyMap = mutableMapOf<Char, Int>(s.first() to 1)
    var left = 0
    var window = 1

    for (right in 1 until s.length) {
        frequencyMap.computeIfPresent(s[right]) { _, frequency -> frequency + 1 }
        frequencyMap.putIfAbsent(s[right], 1)

        val mostFrequentChar = frequencyMap.maxByOrNull { it.value }!!.key
        var additionalElementsCount = frequencyMap.values.sum() - frequencyMap[mostFrequentChar]!!

        while (left != right && additionalElementsCount > k) {
            frequencyMap.computeIfPresent(s[left]) { _, frequency -> frequency - 1 }
            if (frequencyMap[s[left]] == 0) frequencyMap.remove(s[left])
            additionalElementsCount--
            left++
        }

        window = maxOf(window, right - left + 1)
    }

    return window
}
```